# Symfony2: Unrecognized options "method_access_control" under "jms_security_extra" error

Tags: security, symfony

So I'm trying to configure security access for some of my methods here, through JMSSecurityExtraBundle. I simply followed the instructions here : [JMSSecurityBundle Doc](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/method_security_authorization).

I ended up having this in my config.yml file:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_controllers:  true
    secure_all_services: false
    method_access_control:
        'MyBundle:.*:postEntityDelete': 'hasRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")'
```

Now I'm simply getting that error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "method_access_control" under "jms_security_extra"
```

How can I have gone wrong on so little? Where's the catch and how do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Deps :

```
[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
    git=https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle

[metadata]
    git=https://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git
    version=1.1.0 ; <- make sure to get 1.1, not 1.0

[JMSAopBundle]
    git=https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/AopBundle

[cg-library]
    git=https://github.com/schmittjoh/cg-library.git

[JMSDiExtraBundle]
    git=https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/DiExtraBundle
```

Deps.lock:

```
symfony v2.0.13
twig v1.7.0
monolog 1.0.2
doctrine-common 2.1.4
doctrine-dbal 2.1.6
doctrine 2.1.6
swiftmailer v4.1.7
assetic v1.0.3
twig-extensions 446d870272cd87a720e95242eade38a2acf56eaa
metadata 1.0.0
SensioFrameworkExtraBundle cb61b92ed55241d93ed9726bc3f5f47c7d2ce8fe
JMSSecurityExtraBundle e752f888c51425f71382c056961f10f2be642102
SensioDistributionBundle 20b66a408084ad8752f98e50f10533f5245310bf
SensioGeneratorBundle b1ccb78c1743f30817b0fce9bb5c6baff6ed7bf8
AsseticBundle v1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of symfony and of the bundle are you using? The documentation you linked is following the master branch. There are links in the upper left to change versions. 1.0 doesn't seem to have that configuration option.

the deps file should contain:

```
[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
  git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
  target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
  version=origin/master
```

You can also see here for someone else that had the same issue https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/issues/24

Comment: Symfony 2.0 and I've changed the deps for JMSExtraFramework master and not 1.0.x

Comment: maybe there's still an older commit referenced in deps.lock? Take a look at this file in your vendors dir and make sure it contains `method_access_control` somewhere. If not, then you're on an older version. https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

Comment: Yep I'm re installing the bundle now like they advise to.

Comment: No change at all, although now I have extra bundles installed. I still get the same error.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the relevant parts of deps and deps.lock

Comment: yeah, it's not using the master branch of the bundle. I've updated my answer with info that should help.

Comment: Done. I'll add `version=origin/master` and `reinstall`. I had seen the issue but the fix they proposed didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: note the difference between `install` and `update`. If you run `install` it will use whatever commit hash is in deps.lock. In your case that is an old commit. Try running `update`

Comment: I've removed the `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` entry in `deps.lock` file and ran reinstall. I'll update if it still doesn't work.